# Asp.Net Page takes a long time to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am experiencing a strange issue where some sections of the Asp.Net(aspx pages) site are taking a long time to load than others. After going through all the stages of the cycle and getting the page and the master page processed after it exits the code it takes about 20 seconds for the application to get to the Application_EndRequest event. I am not sure what it is doing for those 20 seconds. Since I know what I am telling is not specific I am just asking for suggestions on how to debug the issue or any helpful tips I can follow to see what's the holdup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a code profiler. I used [Stackify's Prefix](https://stackify.com/prefix/) in a similar situation. It's a free download.